# How to create multiple columns from combination of pairs of another column?

Tags: r

I'm trying to create multiple columns which are combinations of pairs based on another column. For example, in this reduced `forcats::gss_cat` dataset, there is a `marital` column with three values: `Separated`, `Divorced`, and `Married`. I'm able to create new columns like `Separated_Divorced` using `mutate` and `case_when`, like this:

**Reduced dataset for simplicity**

```
data <- forcats::gss_cat %>% 
  filter(marital != "No answer") %>% 
  filter(marital != "Never married") %>% 
  filter(marital != "Widowed")

data %>% count(marital)

marital           n
Separated       743         
Divorced       3383         
Married       10117
```

**Manually creating columns based on pairs**

`Separated_Divorced`, `Divorced_Married`, `Married_Separated`

```
data <- data %>% 
  mutate(Separated_Divorced = case_when(marital == "Separated" ~ "Separated",
                                        marital == "Divorced" ~ "Divorced"),
         Divorced_Married = case_when(marital == "Divorced" ~ "Divorced",
                                      marital == "Married" ~ "Married"),
         Married_Separated = case_when(marital == "Married" ~ "Married",
                                       marital == "Separated" ~ "Separated"))
```

Is there a function or a simple way to create these columns without manually creating columns unlike this approach?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may use `combn` on the `levels` of the 'marital'

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data2 <- combn(levels(data$marital), 2, FUN = \(x) 
   data %>%  
     transmute(!! str_c(x, collapse="_") := 
        case_when(as.character(marital) %in% x~ as.character(marital))), 
          simplify = FALSE) %>%
    bind_cols(data, .)
```

-output

```
> head(data2, 2)
# A tibble: 2 × 24
   year marital    age race  rincome        partyid relig denom tvhours `No answer_Neve… `No answer_Sepa… `No answer_Divo… `No answer_Wido… `No answer_Marr… `Never married_…
  <int> <fct>    <int> <fct> <fct>          <fct>   <fct> <fct>   <int> <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>            <chr>           
1  2000 Divorced    48 White $8000 to 9999  Not st… Prot… Bapt…      NA <NA>             <NA>             Divorced         <NA>             <NA>             <NA>            
2  2000 Divorced    25 White Not applicable Not st… None  Not …       1 <NA>             <NA>             Divorced         <NA>             <NA>             <NA>            
# … with 9 more variables: Never married_Divorced <chr>, Never married_Widowed <chr>, Never married_Married <chr>, Separated_Divorced <chr>,
#   Separated_Widowed <chr>, Separated_Married <chr>, Divorced_Widowed <chr>, Divorced_Married <chr>, Widowed_Married <chr>
```